# Java: Declare Variable with ? extends class

Tags: java, generics

i have the following Problem. I have a Interface

```
public interface A<T extends B>
{
   T getObject();
}
```

And i have a class using this interface:

```
public void test()
{
  A<B> a;
  B b = a.getObject();
}
```

This causes an compile error cause the returned Object is B and not extending B.
Is there any way i can declare variable b with ?

Thanks,
Gertrude

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the raw type `A` instead of `A<B> a`?

Comment: You're using a raw type `A`, don't do that. If you don't know `T`, then use `A<?>` instead.

Comment: Start by reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it ... then, in case you still wonder what is going on ... read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. At this point in time, my guess is that you simply lack knowledge about java generics.

Comment: sry i forgot about A<B>, but my question still exists ;)

Comment: if you call a.getObject() without intializing a, then you get a compiler error that `The local variable a may not have been initialized`.

Comment: @SujayMohan this is an example code and not the problem i was asking about

Comment: please go through this link  - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. As per the code shared by you does not cause the error mentioned by you. Unless you provide the code for the implementation of  getObject() is provided and implementation of Object a is provided it is difficult to provide an answer to question with the code provided.

Comment: @user3922628: sample code is fine, usually, but this one doesn't demonstrate the issue you are trying to solve, so it's pointless here.